# MySQL INSERT into junction table

Tags: mysql

All,

I am very new to MySQL queries. Below is what I need to create.

1. employee (emp_id, first_name, last_name, address, manager_id)
            • manager_id is foreign key referencing to employee(emp_id).
2. team (team_id, name, manager_id, project_working_on)
            • manager_id is foreign key referencing to employee (emp_id), project_working_on is
              foreign key referencing to project (project_id).
3. employee_team (emp_id, team_id)
            • emp_id is foreign key referencing to employee (emp_id), team_id is foreign key
              referencing to team(team_id).
4. project (project_id, name, start_date, finish_date, produced_product)
            • produced_product is foreign key referencing to product (product_id).
5. product (product_id, name, cost)
6. customer (cust_id, first_name, last_name, address, phone)
7. customer_product (cust_id, product_id)
            • cust_id is foreign key referencing to customer (cust_id), product_id is foreign key
              referencing to product (product_id).

Task:  Using the INSERT statement, enter 5 (dummy) records in each junction table and 3
records in each remaining table.

I have created all the tables. Now, one of the task is to insert data in junction table.

Q1: I am correct saying junction table is customer_product (cust_id, product_id)  and  employee_team (emp_id, team_id) ?

Q2: if yes, how can I INSERT data into that as these tables only have foreign keys.

Q3: if these are not junction tables then from above; what should I consider as junction table and normal table.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind Regards,

Viku

Answer (score 0):

Q1: yes

Q2: When you want to, for example, insert records into the table 'employee_team' you do this as follows:

```
INSERT INTO employee_team VALUES ('emp_id', 'team_id');
```

emp_id is the id of the employee you want to couple (add) to a team with id: team_id; this means you have to create employees and team(s) first.

Q3: NA

Comment: Thanks Eddy, i have tried to add record in customer_product table using    INSERT into customer_product values ('1','2');   however it is giving me error "Can Not ADD or UPDATE child row: a foreign key constraint fails.  just to mention cust_id and prod_id is primary keys. please advise.

Comment: This probalbly means there's ni customer with cust_id = 1 and/or a product with prod_id = 2; create these first and/or use the ids of existing customers and product in the INSERT-statement.

Comment: Eddy, if i understood well, i need to add records in customer table so that i will have cust_id = 1 and product table with prod_id = 1?

Comment: You need records in the customer and product table. They will have a id (primary key); use this keys in the INSERT-statement to insert a record in the junction table. The value of the ids doesn't have to be 1.

Comment: ok - i have created records in customer and product table. Now, i need to insert (dummy) record in customer_product table. i have below statement:   INSERT into customer_product (cust_id,prod_id) values ('3','4');     however still got the same error. am i doing something wrong here?  i know the cust_id and prod_id is auto_increment ... but then what can i insert in customer_product table?

Comment: Check if: (1) there's a customer, with cust_id =3 (2) there's a product with product_id = 4 (3) the table customer_product has a primary key that has no auto increment setting (4) the foreign keys cust_id and product_id actually reference to the corresponding primary keys in the customer and product table